# Call a laravel endpoint from same app using Guzzle when using Laravel sail (Docker)

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-sail

I have a Laravel app running in Docker containers using Laravel Sail.
I want to call an endpoint of the same laravel app from the same app.

I am using Guzzle HTTP client for that, but since app is running inside the container ( using Sail ) it is not able to connect to it and make request.

I tried using `host.docker.internal` as host for my endpoint but this gives me 502 bad gateway.

which host should I use to make requests inside the same container?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel sail uses artisan serve. Artisan serve not allow nested requests.

More info here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-app-not-responsive-to-other-requests-while-making-guzzle-request

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/api-call-not-returning-a-response